# Scrolling when UIScrollView inside UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, uiscrollview, paging

I want to put a second UIScrollView inside of the first page of another UIScrollView.
To scroll to page 2 of the first UIScrollView I now have to swipe right above oder below the second UIScrollView. Is there a way to ignore a right swipe while being on page 3 of the second UIScrollView so I can scroll to page 2 of the first UIScrollView? Hope you understand my problem :/

[image: UIScrollView inside of UIScrollView]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different approaches.
You could implement the delegate methods of the scroll view `(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender` and `(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender` to observe when the view was scrolled.
Through this you can track the index of the current page of the second scrollview.
I haven't tried it out yet, but something like this should go into the right direction:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    if (indexOfSecondScrollView == 3 && secondScrollView.contentOffSet.x >= 3*second_scroll_view_screen_width){
       firstScrollView.scrollEnabled == YES;
        //move firstScrollView doing something like this:
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height) animated:YES];
    }
    else{
       firstScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```